# eclipse split window switch shortcut key

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody know the shortcut to switch between split windows in Eclipse? I need to quickly navigate window on right and back to left and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> will give you a list of all the files opened in the editor view which you can use to switch between files.